# Oracle APEX 20.2 Problem with the cascading LOV (built on Web Source) in an Interactive Grid

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, lov, oracle-apex-20.2, interactive-grid

I have a master form and a detail interactive grid.

And I have two LOV's on the interactive grid, both of them are built on Rest Web Source.

First LOV is a master & the second one is the cascading LOV with a parameter from the master.

The problem is that the cascading LOV does not fetch any data.

I noticed that when I make the master LOV to be in the form (not in the IG), the cascading LOV works fine and fetches data.

But if both of them are on the IG, the parameter of the first LOV not passed to the cascading LOV, so it returns no rows.

I don't know if this is a bug in APEX 20.2 or what.

if anyone can help, I will appreciate that a lot.

Thanks,

[Master LOV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/be33E.png)

[Cascading LOV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lbis1.png)

[!Parent IG Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlvDI.jpg)

[Child IG Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73OAA.jpg)

Comment: you have to provide a lot of more information for being able to help. How is the cascade lov being configured ? do you have the parent items specified in the cascade lov ? Show us how have you build this page and the section which does not work. As this is APEX you may add pictures

Comment: Hi Sir, yes, the parents item is an IG column, and the cascading LOV is an IG column also. When I make the parent item to be a page item, it works fine, but the if it is IG column, the parameter of this parent IG column is not passed to the cascading LOV

Comment: the problem is in the parameter of the cascading LOV, when I put a static value or page item, it works fine, but when I put an IG column, the parameter did not populated

Comment: any help please

Answer (score 0):

When you turn on Debug, and review debug output for your Interactive Grid, are there any error messages logged?

Can you stage a test case for your issue on apex.oracle.com, so that we can see what you actually implemented and review?
For the test case, you might use SQL Workshop > REST Services to create simple REST APIs on the EMP and DEPT tables, which you could use for REST Data Sources and for the LOVs.

Comment: this is a comment not an answer. Please, use the comment section to interact with the OP if you want to clarify something, or you have doubts about anything in the post.

Comment: Thanks Sir for your comment, no, actually i dont have any errors. I will try to post some print screens

Comment: any help please

Comment: I'm afraid without clear instructions how to reproduce the issue, or even  better: a test case, nobody will be able to help ...